# How do I push text with new div in VueJs?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, pug

Can someone help me set this up? I am trying to create a new div each time someone posts the text. Basically something like facebook newsfeed post. I'm doing something wrong, I do not know what. Do I need a v-for or v-if for  .postSender ?

```
 .wrapper
    .msgSender  
      .msgSenderTop
        img.avatar(src='https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png')
        form
          input#fname(type='text', v-model="newPost" placeholder="Whats on your mind?")
          input.submit(type='submit', value='Submit' @click="sendPost")
    .postSender
      .postSednerTop
        img.avatar(src='https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png')
        .infos
          h3 Your name
          p Timestamp
        hr
      .postSenderBody  
        .msg
          p {{ placeText.post }}
   
export default {
  name: "Home",
 data() {
   return  {
     placeText: [{ post: ''}],
     newPost: ''
   }
  },
  methods: {
    sendPost() {
      this.placeText.push(this.newPost);
      this.newPost = '';
}
```

Comment: Your trying to use `push` on an object. `placeText` is an object, you can't use `push` method on it. Try changing it to an `array`

Comment: I edited my post, should it work this way? Also how can I create a new .postSender div each time I push the post?

Comment: No. Change `placeText` to an `array` and push new posts inside it. And i dont see you anywere iterating on the `placeText`. You have to use `v-for="(post, index) in placeText"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want the user to allow adding multiple post and you want to show them below.

FIrst of change this piece code.

```
export default {
  name: "Home",
  data() {
    return  {
      placeText: [{ post: ''}],
      newPost: ''
    }
   },
   methods: {
    sendPost() {
      this.placeText.push(this.newPost);
      this.newPost = '';
   }
}
```

You have decclared `placeText` as a `array` of `objects` but in the `sendPost` method you are trying to push text in the array, so when you will try to get the text using `placeText.post` you will get `undefined`

Change `sendPost` method to this

```
sendPost() {
  this.placeText.push({ post: this.newPost })
  this.newPost = ''
}
```

Now in your template part you can iterate over the array of posts like this.

```
<div v-for="(item, index) in placeText" :key="index" class="message-send-body">
  <div class="msg" >
    {{item.post}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there way to display the text normally instead like this? `[ " text.." ]`

Comment: Sorry, but what text you are you talking about,

Comment: nevermind, got something wrong. Got it all fixed now.